# Using React stroybook as Jest test

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, jestjs, raw-loader

I have a React storybook and what to use it as my test cases

I have a "loader.js" that import all the stories

```
import sourceBasic from 'raw-loader!./Basics/foo.js?sourceMap';
import Basic from './Basics/foo';

const tree = {
  Basics:[
    {
      title:'Creating and applying a style',
      source:sourceBasic,   element:Basic
    },
    {        ....        }
  ],
  [       ....      ],
  ....
}

export default tree
```

**I use the `raw-loader` and `sourceMap` to show the source with the element in storybook**

This works great.

My problem is when I try to import with Jest

```
FAIL  ./index.test.js
 ● Test suite failed to run

 Cannot find module 'raw-loader!./Basics/foo.js?sourceMap' from 'load.js'

   at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:179:17)
   at Object.<anonymous> (example/stories/load.js:2:34)
```

The test file

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import load from './example/stories/load'

for(const groupName in load ){
  const groupArray = load[groupName];
  describe(groupName, () => {
    for(const item of groupArray ){
      test(item.title, () => {
        const elem = renderer.create(item.element);
        expect(elem.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
      }) // END test
    } // END for
  }) // END describe
} // END for
```

Thanks for your help

**UPDATE**

The update and working **stroybook as test** is implemented on the project [react-outline](https://github.com/codemeasandwich/react-outline)

You can `clone` it([react-outline](https://github.com/codemeasandwich/react-outline)), `npm install` and then `npm test` to see it in action.

Here is the [output on travis](https://travis-ci.org/codemeasandwich/react-outline) :)

Comment: Inline loaders are very fragile because they are webpack specific and won't work with any other tool. I'm not sure if it's even possible to test your specific case with it. Since the use of `raw-loader` is to show the source, you could probably use [`babel-plugin-preval`](https://github.com/kentcdodds/babel-plugin-preval) to read the file from the file system at compile time and include its content. As it is a Babel plugin, you can use it with any tool that uses Babel, so webpack and Jest will both work well.

Comment: Hi @MichaelJungo
I am trying it now. I have installed, wrapped the import but am getting `Error: Cannot resolve module 'preval.macro'`

Comment: Looks like you're using [`preval.macro`](https://github.com/kentcdodds/preval.macro), which is a [Babel macro](https://github.com/kentcdodds/babel-macros). To use it you need to install `babel-macros` and [add it to your Babel config](https://github.com/kentcdodds/babel-macros/blob/master/other/docs/user.md), and of course you also need to install `preval.macro`.

Comment: `npm install --save-dev babel-macros` + `npm install --save-dev preval.macro` + `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-preval` Work! :) now need to try it with the tests

Comment: You're getting mixed up between `babel-plugin-preval` and `preval.macro`. Now that you have `babel-macros` in your `.babelrc` you need to import the `preval.macro` like so: `import preval from 'preval.macro'`. But of course you need to install `preval.macro` before you can use it (it's a regular npm package). `npm install --save-dev preval.macro`. Only when using `babel-plugin-preval` directly (not the macro version), it processes the unbound `preval` identifier. You also don't need to install `babel-plugin-preval` manually if you use `preval.macro` (it's already included as a dependency).

Comment: **Thanks for the help** but after a LOT of digging I we use `"jest": {  "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^raw-loader": "<rootDir>/empty-module.js"
 }}` as I only want to moke it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the `raw-source` and want to mock it. You can use the [moduleNameMapper](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#modulenamemapper-object-string-string) under your [Jest setting within your package.json](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html).

This will let you intercept all `require`/`import` based on a regex match.

Add to your **package.json**:

```
  ...
  "dependencies": {
     ...
  },
  ...

  "jest": {
    "globals": {
      "__TEST__": true
    },
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|jpg|png)$": "<rootDir>/empty-module.js",
      "^raw-loader": "<rootDir>/empty-module.js"
    },
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/"
    ],
    "verbose": true
  }
}
```